# Program runs under WINE on one computer but not another

Tags: wine, playonlinux

I installed an unsupported WINE application in order to use my reMarkable tablet with my Ubuntu install. Initially, it wouldn't run, and spit out the error:

```
Unimplemented function KERNEL32.dll.GetUserPreferredUILanguages called at address
```

I tried out `playonlinux` and a few other options, tried adding some libraries, etc. It now runs just fine, but as far as I can tell, nothing about my WINE configuration is different from when I started.

I'm getting the same error on my work computer and just want to know where I can track down the actual (relevant) configuration settings so that I can attempt to reverse engineer what actually solved the issue. The relevant playonlinux.cfg file on either computer has only the contents

```
ARCH=x86
WINEDEBUG=
```

As far as I can tell, there's no reason the error should have gone away. Anything else to look at?

Comment: did you create a 32 bit prefix? and which version of WINE did PlayOnLinux use?

Comment: I tried both 32 and 64. Working version seems to be 32, but the original install (outside of play) is now inexplicably working also on the same computer that the working play version is on.

Comment: I would check the WINE version that is set to default

Comment: It is. Nothing here helping. Is there any way to list installed components or something?